# Perform a "partial" git reset on a live production server

Tags: git

I want to pull the latest version of my code onto the server. Before I do this I run `git status`:

```
git status
#   config/application.rb
#   uploads/MSEQ.gif
#   uploads/UOjj.gif
#   uploads/gyNa.gif
```

This makes sense, I did fiddle with the config to test something, and some users have uploaded some profile pictures.

However, if I were to run

```
git pull origin master
```

This would result in a merge-conflict, and I don't want to have to use vim as my mergtool, and using a mergetool doesn't feel like a good idea on a live server.

**So my question is, how can I run a `git reset --hard` to 'skim off' these local changes, but keep the three images that have been uploaded intact?**

How should my `.gitignore` file look to stop this happening again?

Locally I have this:

```
# .gitignore

/uploads/*
```

However, I add this to my branch, push it up, and when I try to pull on the server and run git status, it's still telling me about the untracked changes inside uploads. Shouldn't it be ignoring these changes?

Comment: What do you mean by "skim off" the local changes? Please clarify.

Comment: I'm sorry, but to me this question screams: "GIT IS NOT A DEPLOYMENT TOOL". Use a deployment tool.

Comment: Something like `git checkout config/application.rb`

Comment: I think `git stash` will help